# Is Spacy language independent when training NER?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

If I am training a NER model completely from scratch, does the language matter? In the API I set the language, but I also give the API the spans of the named entities. The command-line format goes one step further and I give the NER labels for each token for each sentence. For example, could I tokenize Japanese using ICU, label the tokens, then feed that to Spacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Spacy 2.0, [setting the language to `xx`](https://spacy.io/usage/models#multi-language) will train a language independent model, and the [pipeline can be customized](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#disabling). While the tokenizer, tagger, and parser are all language dependent, the tagger and parser can be disabled. The tokenizer can be skipped if the [GoldParse class](https://spacy.io/usage/training#annotations) is used to provide pre-tokenized input. This is quite easy with the command-line tool. [`spacy train`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#train) has options to disable the tagger and parser and the [input format](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#json-input) is pre-tokenized. [`spacy convert`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#convert) can be used to convert standard NER file formats to Spacy's format.

Answer (score 1):

Spacy uses a [pipeline](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) consist of a tokenizer, tagger, parser and an entity recognizer. it means every level outputs just be fed to next level as input, so for example if I use `en` tokenizer for `fr` tagger no error will happen BUT tokenzier exceptions and norm exceptions in `en` language will affect my `fr` Doc so maybe accuracy will decrease.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the pipeline documentation. It was very helpful.